# QPSQL driver not loaded

Tags: qt, mingw-w64

I know that there are few topics on the Internet about `QPSQL driver not loaded` problem but none of the solutions have helped me.

Let's start from the beggining. This is what I'm using:

```
Windows 7 x64
PostgreSQL 9.3
QtCreator 2.4.1
Based on Qt 4.7.4 (32 bit)
```

First of all I've tried to use tutorial from http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html#qpsql . The problem with that solution is that `cd %QTDIR%` command result is changing my working directory to `C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.4\mingw` which has not any `src` directory but fortunately has got `plugins\sqldrivers`. Unfortunately there is no folder `pqsl`. Even if I ignore that problem and skip into next step - `qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=C:\psql\include" "LIBS+=C:\psql\lib\ms\libpq.lib" psql.pro` it shows me that it `cannot find file psql.pro` and there is no `psql.pro` file in my whole Qt directory. I've decided to leave that solution and to find another one.

Somewhere in the Web I've found that I need to write those lines into my `.pro` file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$quote(C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.3/include)
LIBS += -L$$quote(C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib)
```

I've done that. But the `driver not loaded` problem is still appearing.

What should I do. Am I missing something?

If it helps after running

```
qDebug() << QSqlDatabase::drivers();
```

command it displays only `("QSQLITE")`

P.S. I hope that my problem is understandable - english is not my native language.

Comment: Try asking on http://superuser.com/, they are more geared towards configuration while programming questions are the focus here.

Comment: Maybe the title is a little bit incomprehensible. My problem is not with hardware driver but with Qt-software database driver.

Comment: psql should be located somewhere in: QT-DIR\src\sql\drivers\psql\ for compilation against your system setup

Comment: There is neither folder `src` - like I said in `%QTDIR%` directory nor location similar to that you've typed.

Comment: I have a problem but S.O. linux ubuntu